# where has the file deleted with `sudo trash` gone?

Tags: trash

```
$ pwd
/tmp/test
$ trash mfile 
trash: cannot trash regular file `mfile'
$ sudo trash mfile 
$
```

But I can't find the file under `/home/t/.local/share/Trash/*`

So where has the file deleted with `sudo trash` gone? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## When `/home` is on the same partition

With either `trash` or `sudo trash`, the files usually get stored under `~/.local/share/Trash/files`.

## When `/home` is on a different partition

From [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209217/261076), if `/home` is on a different partition than `/tmp/test`, `sudo trash` will put the files in one or two subfolders of the root folder of `/tmp/test`'s partition (which can be gotten with `df -P /tmp/test | tail -1 | rev | cut -d' ' -f 1 | rev`):

- `.Trash/0/files`
- `.Trash-0/files`

Note that `0` in both is the Linux user ID of the user (root has user ID `0`) who trashed the file. You can run `id [username]` to find out the user ID of a user and then replace `0` with that `uid` number to access that user's trash folder(s) on that partition.

## If you delete two files with the same name

Note that if you trash two files with the same name, the more recently trashed file might be stored with a trailing `_1` on its filename.

Comment: Thanks. But It is not in `~/.local/share/Trash/files`. Also do `trash` and `trash-put` work the same?

Comment: Yes, `trash` and `trash-put` work the same. I've updated my answer with details about what happens when `/home` is on a different partition from `/tmp/test`.

Comment: I was wondering why `sudo ls /.Trash/0/* ` reports 
`ls: cannot access '/.Trash/0/*': No such file or directory` ?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444857/why-does-filename-expansion-not-work-in-this-example

Comment: Related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/445434/how-can-i-manage-a-trash-created-under